# ios 7 document interaction controller hide status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, statusbar

In my iOS app i've hidden the status bar with this code in each ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

In a view I need to use a UIDocumentInteractionController, but when it comes up, the status bar appears, is there a way to keep it hidden?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of the following code and the code from iOS:

```
- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
  // hack to keep status bar visible
  [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:
    ^{
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
  }];
  return self;
}
```

combined with

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this works for me :

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerWillBeginPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `documentController.delegate` to self and use

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
}
```